# Algorithm for Audio - Video Encryption

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, cocoa

I want to perform encryption - decryption of certain audio - video files.

Can anyone suggest me some suitable algorithms in cocoa, objective- c, c, or c++ to accomplish it?

You can suggest me some link and/ or third party software for it.

Thanks,

Miraaj

Comment: Do you really mean encryption/decryption, or do you mean encoding/decoding?

Comment: I mean encryption and decryption!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any stream cipher should work for you. I would suggest [AES](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). Numerous FOSS implementations are available.

Here's a quick link that might help: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by encryption?  Do you mean you actually want to encipher an audio file?  If that's the case, then any general cryptographic algorithm will work (AES, RSA, etc.).  If you mean the audio has DRM that you want to decrypt, then it depends on the type of DRM.  If you mean you want to decode the audio (decompress the file and be able to play the audio) then that will depend on the file type.

I'm assuming you want to do the latter, in which case you might want to check out [ffmpeg](http://stephenjungels.com/jungels.net/articles/ffmpeg-howto.html) - a free (GPL) library that can decode audio and video.

Answer (score 1):

Absent a specific reason to choose something else, I'd probably use AES. A search for something like "AES C++ source code" should turn up quite a few implementations.